# SLEEP , CAST, REGEXP QUERY EXPLANATION

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM tb WHERE id=1 
AND 
sleep(CAST((SELECT 'a' REGEXP '^[n-z]') AS signed) * 15);
```

I'm trying to understand how it works.

1)   SELECT * FROM tb WHERE id=1  # that's simple no explanation needed

2)  `sleep(CAST((SELECT 'a' REGEXP '^[n-z]') AS signed) * 15);` # Here it's a knotty problem
for me.

I believe things are: sleep for (the result of --> CAST((SELECT 'a' REGEXP '^[n-z]') AS signed) multiplied by 15.

My concerns are:

- CAST is a function to convert (for instance from string to date) but here it is used to convert a string in a signed number ..is that correct?
- REGEXP, I believe is used this way: `(SELECT 'a' REGEXP '^[n-z]')` returns 0 (zero) so multiplied by 15 is always 0. But `(SELECT 'p' REGEXP '^[n-z]')` returns 1 so in this case the DBMS sleeps for 15 sec.

So, now the final question is:

- if tb has only one record whose name is 'bob', is the database going to pause for 15 sec?

Comment: Where did you find this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if tb has only one record whose name is 'bob', is the database going to pause for 15 sec?

No, with **this** query the database is never gonna pause because `CAST((SELECT 'a' REGEXP '^[n-z]') AS signed) * 15` always returns 0, totally independent from your records: It does not use any column from the table, 'a' is a string literal.

But other than that, you analyzed it correct. The query as you shown it does not make any sense.